# MS Office 365 hangs on emails "Contacting:\\feeds.feedburner.com"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rss, office365

I have one incoming email that my office 365 stalls on. I always get the same message:  `Contacing:\\feeds.feedburner.com\~r\MinimalistBaker\~4`.

I saw another line of questioning regarding Office 2010 with an easy fix of upgrading to Office 2013 ([Outlook hangs on emails that have images with invalid network paths](https://superuser.com/questions/444175/outlook-hangs-on-emails-that-have-images-with-invalid-network-paths)) where there was also a mention of disabling feeds.feedburner.com:  "In my case the emails had an image attempting to load from //feeds.feedburner.com blocking that network location is rather severe though if you run an RSS reader".  I am willing to block it as I don't believe I run an RSS Reader.  Any suggestions on how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

[The answer](https://superuser.com/a/849750/23133) you read about blocking it suggests how to do it. Edit your hosts file and add a record to redirect feeds.feedburner.com to your local loopback interface.

> *One "solution" is to [edit your hosts file](http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/?id=871) to map img.youtube.com to your local IP address* (127.0.0.1) so it fails instantly, rather than taking 1 minute to fail to find \img.youtube.com.
>
> In my case the emails had an image attempting to load from //feeds.feedburner.com blocking that network location is rather severe though if you run an RSS reader.

Just use `feeds.feedburner.com` instead of the `img.youtube.com` in the example.